# error 'require is not a function' when exported and required correctly

Tags: node.js

I am not exactly a node newbie, but this issue has me stumped. Basically, this is an issue for me, nobody else on my team. After the usual npm install etc, calling a function returns `require(...) is not a function`. I have exported it properly and am passing in the parameter properly and again, this seems to be limited to me. Any suggestions?

**Function file**

```
const logger = require('../util/logger')('someParam');
                                       ^Fails here
```

**Logger file:**

```
function logger(param) {
  console.log('this is the param: ', param);
}

module.exports = logger;
```

I have tried this in node 4.4.2, 6.10.2 and 7.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question. After some time, I decided to reclone the repo and npm install again, and the issue did not present itself. I have no idea what caused the issue as my code was the same as a fresh clone. One of those things.